# Randomly generating integer without repetition, no arrays

Tags: java, memory, random

I'm writing a program that has 6 different pictures and displays 12 tiles, with two of each picture.  It is a memory game, and I am working on generating a random tile placement.  I need to use RandomIntGenerator to distribute the tiles throughout the board, but I can't think of a way to do this since RandomIntGenerator will duplicate numbers.  I'm not allowed to use arrays, which would have made this much easier.  Can you give me any insight into how this could be done?

Any help is really appreciated!
-Ryan

Comment: `RandomIntGenerator` is not a class I know about, but to help you a little, search the help for `HashSet`.

Answer (score 7):

Create a `List<Integer>` with 12 values (1-12)

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(12);
for(int i = 0; i < 12 ; i++){ list.add(i);}
```

and then shuffle it

[`Collections.suffle(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: that's pretty awesome!

Answer (score 2):

yes, it seems you need random shuffle of your cards. You could implement your version of simple [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) shuffling, for example, or indeed, use `Collections.shuffle()`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
int suggestedPlacement = RandomIntGenerator.next();

while (tileAlreadyTaken(suggestedPlacement)) {
  suggestedPlacement = RandomIntGenerator.next();
}
```

Comment: The question is more about how to implement the tileAlreadyTaken part of this logic without maintaining an array of tiles that have been taken.

Comment: what is RandomIntGenerator ? could you please link javadoc

Answer (score 0):

```
long pattern = 0b111111;
Random r = new Random();
while (pattern != 0) {
    int n = r.nextInt(6);
    long mask = 1 << n;
    if ((pattern & mask) == 0) continue;
    pattern ^= mask;
    System.out.println("n = " + n);
}
```

Comment: Some comments would help improve this answer

Comment: i have simply propose to use bitmask instead of array for avoidance of duplicates. imho code is very primitive